# Kotlin .let {} null safety presumably false error

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

When using the `.let { }` function I noticed that when doing the following:

```
bucket?.assignedVariantName.let {
        bucket?.determineVariant()  <-- guarantee safety for bucket
}
```

You have to guarantee safety for bucket in this case i.e.  `bucket?.` or `bucket!!` while null safety is already guaranteed by using `?.let` then I noticed when doing the following:

```
bucket?.assignedVariantName?.let { <-- added safety check for property 
        bucket.determineVariant()  <-- doesn't need to guarantee safety for bucket
}
```

Whilst using let on the property of the bucket and not directly on bucket I'm wondering if this is intentionally or a bug in Kotlin plugin (in this case I encountered this in Android Studio)

Additional info is that bucket is in this case a `local val` while assignedVariantName is a nullable var.

```
val bucket: T? = ...
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The [`.let { ... }` function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) is defined as

```
inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R = block(this)
```

`T` can be a nullable type, and `let` can be called on a null receiver, `null.let { }` is valid code.

Now take a look at the two calls:

- `bucket?.assignedVariantName.let { ... }`.

  Here, `let` is always called regardless of whether the receiver `bucket?.assignedVariantName` is null or not.

  There is a possible case when `bucket?.assignedVariantName` is null because `bucket` is null -- then `null` is just passed into `let`, and it is definitely not safe to use `bucket` inside the `let` block.

  <sup>[(runnable example of the case)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/f0f56u4kt9nv49n61khp9kpc75/abhhfrp20208ut651bn5ek92n5)</sup>
- `bucket?.assignedVariantName?.let { ... }`

  In this case, `let` is called only if the receiver `bucket?.assignedVariantName` is not null, requiring that `bucket` is not null and its `assignedVariantName` is not null. This requirement makes it safe to use `bucket` inside the `let` block.